# format of raster calculator expression in ArcPy for ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator

I'm trying to write a raster value inverter based on a raster calculator expression.

[Article ID: 000006694 Link](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006694)

The pure math would be:
(([elevgrd] - Z_Max) * -1) + Z_Min

Anyhow, I can't figure out how to write the expression. I started with .format and that failed with unicode errors, I then thought if I can get it out as a text string that might help, I copied the sting format (kinda) by exporting a model builder model of the populated geoprocessing tool..

But after 3 hours of swear at one line, I'm out of ideas..

```
    import arcpy
    from arcpy.sa import *
    InputRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    OutputRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    desc = arcpy.Describe(InputRaster)
    RasterPath = (desc.catalogPath)

    RasterPropsMINIMUM = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(InputRaster,"MINIMUM")
    MIN = (RasterPropsMINIMUM.getOutput(0))
    RasterPropsMAXIMUM = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(InputRaster,"MAXIMUM")
    MAX = (RasterPropsMAXIMUM.getOutput(0))

    expression=("\""+"\""+"\""+"("+"\"" +str(RasterPath) +"\"" +" - "+str(MAX) +" )*-1) +"+str(MIN)+"\""+"\""+"\"")
    arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa((expression), OutputRaster)
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to post your error as text, please?  That way it is available to future searches.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following approach.

```
env.workspace = r"path/to/workspace"
RasterPath = Raster(r"your_raster.tif")
ResultRasterPath = r"result.tif"

Max = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(RasterPath, "MAXIMUM"))
Min = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(RasterPath, "MINIMUM"))

MaxNumber = float(Max.replace(',','.'))
MinNumber = float(Min.replace(',','.'))

Result =(((RasterPath - (float(MaxNumber)))*(-1)) + (float(MinNumber)))
Result.save(ResultRasterPath)
```

Comment: Or just rast = arcpy.Raster(r"your_raster.tif") and then rast.maximum and rast.minimum. https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000